# Proving that if the sequence $X_n$ converges to $x$, then ${X_n}^a$, where $a$ is a positive rational, converges to $x^a$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, roots

I've been stuck on this problem for a while. I splitted a into $p/q$, so it would be $({X_n}^p)^{1/q}$, and I got the convergence of ${X_n}^p$ to be $x^p$ since it is just induction using the product rule, but I cannot figure our how to manipulate the definition of convergence (for each $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $N\ge k$ such that $|X_n-x| < \varepsilon$, if $n\ge N$) for something to a $n$-th root.

The closest literature I can find is [this handout](http://www.math.uakron.edu/~dpstory/tutorial/c1/c1l_tp.pdf), but I don't understand how he went from step 1 to 2 and then to 3 in part 32 on slide 23. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows because $f(x)=x^a$ is continuous, ie, $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ if $x_n \to x$.

Edit: if you want to use the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition, observe that the binomial theorem gives

$$x+h \leq (\sqrt[n]{x}+\sqrt[n]{h})^n $$
$$ \sqrt[n]{x+h} \leq \sqrt[n]{x}+\sqrt[n]{h}$$
$$\sqrt[n]{x+h} - \sqrt[n]{x} \leq \sqrt[n]{h}, (*)$$

for $x,h>0$.  By picking $\delta=\epsilon^n$ and using the above inequality, you should now be able to show $\sqrt[n]{x}$ is continuous.

Edit: If you are still confused, suppose $y,z>0$ and $|y-z|=h<\delta$.  Then there are two cases.

If $z=y+h$, then (*) gives $\sqrt[n]{z} - \sqrt[n]{y} \leq \sqrt[n]{h} < \sqrt[n]{\delta}$.

If $y=z+h$, then (*) gives $\sqrt[n]{y} - \sqrt[n]{z} \leq \sqrt[n]{h} < \sqrt[n]{\delta}$.

In EITHER CASE, $|\sqrt[n]{z} - \sqrt[n]{y}| < \sqrt[n]{\delta}$.

In short, 
$$|y-z|<\delta \implies  |\sqrt[n]{z} - \sqrt[n]{y}| < \sqrt[n]{\delta},$$
which should be enough to prove your result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I managed to reduce it to Xn^(1/q) - x^(1/q) < epsilon, but I can't seem to prove that (x^(1/q) - delta^(1/q))^q <= (x - delta) using the binomial theorem, since it might not be true if q is even. Any help?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Pick $N$ so that $n>N$ implies $|x - x_n| < \epsilon^q$.  Then by what I said in the answer, it follows that $|\sqrt[q]{x_n}-\sqrt[q]{x}| < \epsilon$.  So $\sqrt[q]{x_n} \to \sqrt[q]{x}$.

Comment: Since the first statement shows that Xn < x + e^q, and therefore (Xn)^(1/n)  < (x + e^q)^(1/n), we know that by substitution (Xn)^(1/n) - x^(1/n) < e. How does it follow that we can apply the absolute value? That's the part I'm confused about.

Comment: I don't follow you.  In the answer I proved that if two positive numbers $x,y$ satisfy $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|x^{1/n}-y^{1/n}| < \delta^{1/n}$.  Do you agree with this? Maybe I should point out that we can assume $y>x$ without loss of generality?

Comment: Isn't that the conclusion, though? I'll try and clarify what I meant. We know that (x+delta)^(1/n) -x^(1/n) <= delta^(1/n). Then, since |x-Xn|<delta, we know that Xn<x+delta. Then, (Xn)^(1/n)<(x+delta)^(1/n), so therefore (Xn)^(1/n)-x^(1/n) < delta^(1/n) by the first statement through substitution. However, we want the format |(Xn)^(1/n)-x^(1/n)| < delta^(1/n). How can we add an absolute value, since it might not be true that (Xn)^(1/n)>x^(1/n)-delta^(1/n)?

Comment: See the new edit I made to my answer.  Does this help?

Comment: Yeah, I think I got it now. Thank you.